# menu flyout mouse left click

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm a little bit lost, I have a `ContextFlyout` in a `TextBlock`, and it works with right mouse click, but I want it to work with left mouse click.
How can I do it? Is this the wrong way to display the menu?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Livro1Texto" Text="Livro 1" >
 <TextBlock.ContextFlyout>                                 
  <MenuFlyout>
     <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Título I Da Lei Criminal">
       <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Princípios Gerais">                                            
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 1º Princípio da legalidade" x:Name="Art1Fly" Click="Art1Fly_Click"/>
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 2º Aplicação no tempo"  x:Name="Art2Fly" Click="Art2Fly_Click"/>
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 3º Momento da prática do fato" />
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 4º Aplicação no espaço: princípio geral"/>
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 5º Fatos praticados fora do território português"/>
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 6º Restrições à aplicação da lei portuguesa"/>
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 7º Lugar da pratica do fato" />
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 8º Aplicação subsidiária do Código Penal"/>
         <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 9º Disposições especiais para jovens"/>
         </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
         </MenuFlyoutSubItem>

      <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Título II Do Facto"/>
    </MenuFlyout>
 </TextBlock.ContextFlyout>   
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Erm, isn't it kind of the point of a context-menu to be available on right click? I guess you need to use another component (I am not familiar with uwp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I want it to work with left mouse click. How can I do it?

For your requirement, you could use [`FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.flyoutbase#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_Primitives_FlyoutBase_AttachedFlyoutProperty) to realize this feature.

To associate a `MenuFlyout` with `TextBlock`, use the FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout attached property. When a `MenuFlyout` is assigned to other UI elements using `FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout`, you must call either the `ShowAt` method or the static `ShowAttachedFlyout` method to display the flyout.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Livro1Texto" Text="Livro 1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Tapped="Livro1Texto_Tapped">
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
           <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Título I Da Lei Criminal">
                <MenuFlyoutSubItem Text="Princípios Gerais">
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 1º Princípio da legalidade" x:Name="Art1Fly" Click="Art1Fly_Click" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 2º Aplicação no tempo"  x:Name="Art2Fly" Click="Art2Fly_Click" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 3º Momento da prática do fato" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 4º Aplicação no espaço: princípio geral" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 5º Fatos praticados fora do território português" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 6º Restrições à aplicação da lei portuguesa" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 7º Lugar da pratica do fato" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 8º Aplicação subsidiária do Código Penal" />
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Artigo 9º Disposições especiais para jovens" />
                </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
            </MenuFlyoutSubItem>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Título II Do Facto" />
        </MenuFlyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</TextBlock>
```

Invoke `ShowAttachedFlyout` in `TextBlock` `Tapped` event handler.

```
private void Livro1Texto_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     FrameworkElement element = sender as FrameworkElement;
     if (element != null)
     {
         FlyoutBase.ShowAttachedFlyout(element);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you Nico Zhu - MSFT, it was exactly what i wanted, i had alredy tried to use the FlyoutBase, but with out sucess. The only thing i had to change was this:  Flyout.ShowAttachedFlyout(Livro1Texto);